# PowerMock(ito): How to test a private method and mock a pulic service inside another private method

Tags: java, powermock, powermockito

The situation is that there is a private method that first will call a public method on a service and after that calls another private method.

I know that private method calling other private method is not the way it supposed to be. However, I'm still wondering if there is a solution for this issue.

Is there a way that I can invoke the private method and mock the public service method and then verify if the private method inside this private method is called?

Situation is little bit like this:

```
private nameMethod(String param, String param2){
    String value = service.getValues(String someValue); // this is the public service method
    String value2 = checkString(String someText, String someText2) // this is the private method
}
```

So I would like to invoke the nameMethod, mock the service public method getValues and verify if the checkString private method is called

Comment: you could create a new class in your test, which extends the class with the private methods. In your test class override the methods and make them public. Then you can check the usage of these public methods

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you mean to create an inner class in my test class and inside this inner class to re-create the private methods als public methods and put Override above them? Because I get an error for the @Override when I do this about making the original class abstract.

Comment: Sorry, I was using the wrong term. Changing the visibility of a method in a class extending an other class is correctly not overriding - it is more of hiding the original method. So you cannot put the annotation on that method. So my above idea will probably not work.